# Работа с условием

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет! Задание звучит так: "Получить перечень военных специальностей, по которым в округе, в отдельной армии, дивизии, корпусе, военной части более двух специалистов". Пытаюсь это реализовать через проверку.
Вот два варианта моих потугов:
1.

```
SELECT sostav.special,
CASE
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(sostav.special) FROM sostav, chast
            WHERE chast.Num_subdivision = sostav.Num_subdivision
            AND chast.Name_army = "Вторая"
            AND chast.Type_i_num_union = "Дивизия №2"
            AND sostav.Num_constructions = "Корпус №2"
            AND chast.Name_chasti = "Танковая") > 2
 
        THEN (SELECT sostav.special FROM sostav, chast
                WHERE chast.Num_subdivision = sostav.Num_subdivision
                AND chast.Name_army = "Вторая")
END
FROM sostav
```

2. 

```
SELECT sostav.special,
IF ((SELECT COUNT(sostav.special) FROM sostav, chast
        WHERE chast.Num_subdivision = sostav.Num_subdivision
        AND chast.Name_army = "Вторая"
        AND chast.Type_i_num_union = "Дивизия №2"
        AND sostav.Num_constructions = "Корпус №2"
        AND chast.Name_chasti = "Танковая") > 2, 
        (SELECT sostav.special FROM sostav, chast
        WHERE chast.Num_subdivision = sostav.Num_subdivision
        AND chast.Name_army = "Вторая"),
        "Меньше 1")
FROM sostav
```

Проблема вся в том, что я всё время ловлю ошибку "1242: Subquery returns more than 1 row". Как исправить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: "Как исправить?" - надо чтобы олдин из подзапросов не возвращал больше чем 1 результат.. о чём и говорится в ошибке

Comment: Если взять по отдельности запросы, то все они выводят по одной колонке данных. В COUNT() выводится одна строка, ответ на истину проверки отправляется запрос, который также выводит однку колонку данных, но две строки. Может проблема из-за этого?

Comment: Добавьте `CREATE TABLE` и `INSERT INTO` к вопросу. А также укажите версию